# mac: mysql-connector-python connection issues on localhost

Tags: python, mysql, macos, networking

I am trying to walk through some basic tutorials to refresh myself with using MySQL with python3, and am hitting a snag immediately:

```
import mysql.connector

host='localhost'
user='root'
passwd='pwd'

mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host=host, user=user, password=passwd)
```

Running this, I get the error `mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (61 Connection refused)`

I can't find information on what I need to do outside of python to get this to work, it's not clear what authentication it's referring to.  My unix username and password?  I certainly don't want to store the latter in plaintext.  I could enter it in manually (rather not).  Is there a minimal set of instructions to get to the point where I can set up a cursor? Is there a way to set this up without a username and password? Any setup outside of my python environment I need to do, like in ipconfig/ifconfig?

Comment: Is a mysqld process even running on localhost? Can you connect to it using the mysql client or with telnet? There are more troubleshooting tips here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Comment: Not only is it not running, it's not installed.  The instructions I were following seem  to have assumed I had done prerequisites that I hadn't, but didn't mention it. :)

I'll try to get that done using https://flaviocopes.com/mysql-how-to-install/, and can post my results as an answer, unless you or anyone wants to answer with the assumption that the user has done nothing in advance when trying to set up an sql+python database.

Comment: It's probably not the best use of anyone's time to duplicate existing tutorials.